# How to concatenate all lines from a file in Bash?

Tags: bash, shell, loops, while-loop

I have a file `csv` :

```
data1,data2,data2
data3,data4,data5
data6,data7,data8
```

I want to convert it to (Contained in a variable):

`variable`=`data1,data2,data2%0D%0Adata3,data4,data5%0D%0Adata6,data7,data8`

My attempt :

```
data=''
cat csv | while read line
do
data="${data}%0D%0A${line}"
done
echo $data  # Fails, since data remains empty (loop emulates a sub-shell and looses data)
```

Please help..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In bash,

```
data=$(
while read line
do
  echo -n "%0D%0A${line}"
done < csv)
```

In non-bash shells, you can use `` `...` `` instead of `$(...)`.  Also, `echo -n`, which suppresses the newline, is unfortunately not completely portable, but again this will work in bash.

Comment: Getting extra spaces : this,is,some,data%0D%0A this,is,again,data%0D%0A third,line,of,data%0D%0A fourth,line,in,data%0D%0A

Comment: Right... doh.  Edited to add `echo -n`.

Comment: FYI, `$()` is standard. Has been for years. If you want a portable `echo -n` use `printf`

Answer (score 21):

Simpler to just strip newlines from the file:

```
tr '\n' '' < yourfile.txt > concatfile.txt
```

Comment: `tr '\n' '' < csv` prints out the value, like your original script did. If you didn't need it in a variable in bash – sounds like you do – you'd have been able to forego it entirely.

Comment: Didn't "just work" for me, but led me to `tr -d '\n'` which worked great: thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Some of these answers are incredibly complicated. How about this.

```
 data="$(xargs printf ',%s' < csv | cut -b 2-)"
```

or

```
 data="$(tr '\n' ',' < csv | cut -b 2-)"
```

Too "external utility" for you?

```
IFS=$'\n', read -d'\0' -a data < csv
```

Now you have an array! Output it however you like, perhaps with

```
data="$(tr ' ' , <<<"${data[@]}")"
```

Still too "external utility?" Well fine,

```
data="$(printf "${data[0]}" ; printf ',%s' "${data[@]:1:${#data}}")"
```

Yes, `printf` can be a builtin. If it isn't but your `echo` is and it supports `-n`, use `echo -n` instead:

```
data="$(echo -n "${data[0]}" ; for d in "${data[@]:1:${#data[@]}}" ; do echo -n ,"$d" ; done)"
```

Okay, now I admit that I am getting a bit silly. Andrew's answer is perfectly correct.

Answer (score 3):

I would much prefer a loop:

```
for line in $(cat file.txt); do echo -n $line; done
```

Note: This solution requires the input file to have a new line at the end of the file or it will drop the last line.

Comment: @Julien, you could prepend "echo "" >> file.txt"

Comment: It is not always possible to modify the source file. You could also use a temporary copy. Anyway, you're solution is valid; it's just worth to mention its limitations or pitfalls.

Answer (score 2):

Another short bash solution

```
variable=$(
  RS=""
  while read line; do
    printf "%s%s" "$RS" "$line"
    RS='%0D%0A'
  done < filename
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk 'END { print r }
{ r = r ? r OFS $0 : $0 }
  ' OFS='%0D%0A' infile
```

With *shell*:

```
data=

while IFS= read -r; do
  [ -n "$data" ] &&
     data=$data%0D%0A$REPLY ||
    data=$REPLY
done < infile

printf '%s\n' "$data"
```

Recent *bash* versions:

```
data=

while IFS= read -r; do
  [[ -n $data ]] &&
     data+=%0D%0A$REPLY ||
    data=$REPLY
done < infile

printf '%s\n' "$data"
```

Answer (score 1):

A very simple single-line solution which requires no extra files as its quite easy to understand (I think, just cat the file together and perform sed-replace):

```
output=$(echo $(cat ./myFile.txt) | sed 's/ /%0D%0A/g')
```

Answer (score 0):

Useless use of cat, punished! You want to feed the CSV into the loop

```
while read line; do 
 # ...
done < csv
```

Comment: Getting extra spaces : this,is,some,data%0D%0A this,is,again,data%0D%0A third,line,of,data%0D%0A fourth,line,in,data%0D%0A

Comment: Interesting, I don't. Are they in the source file or your shell expression maybe?